# Complete Case Milestone

Tags: case, case-object, casemilestone

I have a scenario where multi level escalation works.

I.E. when a case is escalated it escalates to the owner's manager and again, it escalates to the manager's manager. After the first escalation i'm updating a case Field to True in Milestone and and on True running the second escalation. However. my escalation stops at the first stage.

I.E. I cant go to second milestone until I complete the first milestone .I've tried to complete the first case milestone using both trigger and process Builder.Both work when I update the field manually.

Is there any way i can run both Milestones subsequently?

[image]

Comment: How you defined your milestone types? Can you share your code to get more insights?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Close the first Milestone using Process Builder. 
Note: You didn't provide the name of the escalation fields in your use case.

So lets say you had 2 checkbox fields called Escalation1 and Escalation2
(hidden on page layout of course)

1. Create a Process on the Case Object (Choose Object Case)
   Choose: When a record is Created or Edited
2. Add Criteria:
   Criteria Name: 
    Close Milestone1

   Criteria for executing actions: 
    Conditions are Met
3. Set Conditions:
   FIELD                OPERATOR  TYPE       VALUE
   [Case].Escalation1   Equals    BOOLEAN     TRUE
4. Conditions
   X All of the conditions are met (AND)
5. Advanced
   Do you want to execute the actions only when specified 
   changes are made to the record?
   X YES

=== Next Step Immediate Actions

Action Name 
1. Action Name
   Close Milestone1

2. Record
   [Case].CaseMilestones
3. Criteria for Updating Records
   X Updated records meet all conditions

Field                  Operator       Type  Value
Milestone Type ID.     Equals         ID        557180000008OZf (Used the ID Of YOUR Milestone1)

Set new field values for the records you update
Field               Type    Value
Completion Date.    Formula.    NOW()

This will do it my friend - I'm running it now....

Answer (score 0):

In my Case ,I'd more then 13 Entitlement Process and more then 52 Milestones .So As per your approach I'd have to create Many process builders .

so ,Instead of creating second milestones I just created another time trigger on First milestones and send Email using Email Alert to second level manager. Also,I made a Trigger on Case whenever it Closes it will untag the Entitlement Process.